# apache beam groupby shuffle randomness quality?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

In my apache beam pipeline , i read terabytes of log events. Those events are usually on gcs buckets ordered into hierarchal time buckets. I use the textIO or avroIO readALL and readALLgenericRecords api to read all of them into a pcollection.

```
PCollection<KV<String, GenericRecord>> collection1 = p.apply(Create.of(files...))
   .apply(AvroIO.readAllGenericRecords(schema)).apply(..extract request ID)

PCollection<KV<String, GenericRecord>> collection2 = p.apply(Create.of(files_2...))
   .apply(AvroIO.readAllGenericRecords(schema)).apply(..extract request ID)

PCollection<KV<String, KV<GenericRecord, GenericRecord>>> joinedRecord = 
     KeyedPCollectionTuple.of(collection1).and(collection2)
    .apply(CoGroupByKey.create());
```

Next i try to join them to another pcollection using the request_id , which is basically a random uuid . Since apache beam and dataflow use groupBy as primitives to do the join , does this ensure the final joined data that is generated after the join is essentially shuffled. Is this guaranteed ? 
If i read two streams of data bounded pcollection) and join them using some random uuid , is it guaranteed that beam/dataflow produces a good enough shuffling for the joined dataset ?

Comment: Please share some of your code

Comment: i added the code even though code is really not important here. I want to understand that does the coGroupBy and groupBy primitive used for joining based on some random uuid , essentially generates well shuffled collection ?

Comment: What characteristics are you looking for when you ask about the data being "well shuffled"? If you join based on a random uuid, then the randomness is as good as your random uuid generator.

Comment: my concern was because i read off all these events from a time structured files , and then try to join them as one big bounded input , if my final out put after the join is also some what having similar temporal characteristic and if i need to explicitly shuffle again using random key, but because i join them based on random uuid assigned , if the group by essentially guarantees a shuffle i probably don't have to do a shuffle again since the join took care of the shuffling itself ?

Comment: The CoGroupByKey [https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/group-by-key#joins-with-cogroupbykey] lets you group together all of the values (of any type) in multiple collections that share a common key, it is shuffled by key.